# use Laravel as client to listen to event stream (SSE)?

Tags: laravel

It's clear how to use Laravel to send event-streams (SSE), e.g.
https://devdojo.com/bobbyiliev/how-to-create-a-simple-event-streaming-in-laravel

But, how to use Laravel (or PHP) as a client, i.e. subscribe to an event-stream from an external server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full example based on [@Eman's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77010440/678951) to look at Symfony's HTTP Client. That one has support for Server-Sent Events.

Pretty much following the example as given in the documentation.
Exception: manually constructing `->request()` because the default [`->connect()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2d5340944f934cedf50f54285803fe6e34fec0bd/src/Symfony/Component/HttpClient/EventSourceHttpClient.php#L42-L51) is hard coded to use `GET` (and for GraphQL we need `POST` for the GraphQL subscription).

```
// composer require symfony/http-client 

use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Chunk\ServerSentEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\EventSourceHttpClient;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

$client = HttpClient::create();
$client = new EventSourceHttpClient($client, reconnectionTime: 2);

$url = "...";
$graphql = "...";
$operationName = "...";

$headers = [
    // 'api-key' => "...",
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Accept' => 'text/event-stream', // normally set by ->connect()
    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache', // normally set by ->connect()
];

$body = json_encode([
    'query' => $graphql,
    'variables' => [],
    'operationName' => $operationName
]);

$source = $client->request(
    method: 'POST',
    url: $url,
    options: [
        'buffer' => false,
        'headers' => $headers,
        'body' => $body,
    ],
);

while ($source) {
    foreach ($client->stream($source) as $chunk) {
        if ($chunk instanceof ServerSentEvent) {
            dump($chunk->getArrayData());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be better ways, but this is the approach I ended up using (in my case, for GraphQL subscription over SSE):

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept' => 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
    ]
]);

$body = json_encode([
    'query' => $graphql,
    'variables' => [],
    'operationName' => $operationName
]);

$response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
    'body' => $body,
    'stream' => true,
]);

$response->getBody();

while (!$body->eof()) {
    echo $body->read(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting this here for anyone who's looking for another way.

I discovered Symfony's [HTTP Client](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#consuming-server-sent-events) has a way to handle SSEs and seems to be the nicest one out of everything else I've tried to look at. I believe Laravel already grabs this component so it shouldn't be anything extra you need to do, but even if you do, it's well worth it honestly.

Comment: Great suggestion. Will add complete example as alternative solution. BTW. Laravel's HTTP client is built around Guzzle, not Symfony's.

Comment: I'm aware, but I like Symfony's HTTP better and this is one reason why.

Comment: I can understand. Was referring to you saying "I believe Laravel already grabs this component".

Comment: it was already in my project, so something else I'm using must be using it, so that's why I but a "might be there" clause in my answer.